# Agregar una lista a HTML

Tags: c#, html5, visual-studio-2015, razor, itextsharp

Trabajo con Windows Forms, C#, Razor Engine, ItextSharp 5

Estoy creando un pdf a partir de una plantilla html, no puedo escribir el detalle en el html.

Los datos que van a ir en el html los obtengo de un xml el detalle lo obtengo por medio de un for each poniendo todos los detalles en una lista.

```
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
        {
            var factura = (factura)serializer.Deserialize(ms);
            var list = new List<DetalleFactura>();

            //Recorro todos el detallede la factura
            foreach (var encontrado in factura.detalles)
            {
                var entity = new DetalleFactura()
                {
                    CodigoPrincipal = encontrado.codigoPrincipal,
                    Cantidad = $"{Convert.ToInt32(encontrado.cantidad):N2}",
                    PrecioUnitario = encontrado.precioUnitario,
                    Descuento = encontrado.descuento,
                    PrecioTotal = encontrado.precioTotalSinImpuesto
                };
                list.Add(entity); //Lo agrego a la lista.
            }

            var template = readText;
            var model = new FacturaViewModel()
            {
                Ambiente = factura.infoTributaria.ambiente,
                RazonSocial = factura.infoTributaria.razonSocial,
                Ruc = Convert.ToString(factura.infoTributaria.ruc),
                DireccionMatriz = factura.infoTributaria.dirMatriz,
                ClaveAcceso = factura.infoTributaria.claveAcceso,
                Estableciento = $"{Convert.ToInt32(factura.infoTributaria.estab):000}",
                PuntoEmision = Convert.ToString(factura.infoTributaria.ptoEmi),
                Secuencial = $"{Convert.ToInt32(factura.infoTributaria.secuencial):000000000}", 
                RazonSocialComprador = factura.infoFactura.razonSocialComprador,
                IdentificacionComprador = Convert.ToString(factura.infoFactura.identificacionComprador),
                DireccionComprador = factura.infoFactura.direccionComprador,
                TotalSinImpuestos = factura.infoFactura.totalSinImpuestos,
                FilasDetalle = list //Le asigno la lista.
            };

            var result = Engine.Razor.RunCompile(template, "Key", null, model);
```

Pero no se escribe en la plantilla html. Esto es viéndolo en el depurador

```
<table border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr bgcolor="#F5B041" style="font-size:8.0pt;">
                            <td width="8" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Principal</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Auxiliar</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="6" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cant.</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Descripción</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Detalle Adicional</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">P/U</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">Desc.</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">Precio Total</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CrearReportePDF.Models.DetalleFactura]
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Eso es lo que me imprime, en la plantilla tengo lo siguiente.

```
<table border="0">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr bgcolor="#F5B041" style="font-size:8.0pt;">
                            <td width="8" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Principal</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Auxiliar</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="6" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Cant.</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="40" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Descripción</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="20" valign="top" align="left">
                                <b style="color:white;">Detalle Adicional</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">P/U</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">Desc.</b>
                            </td>
                            <td width="7" valign="top" align="right">
                                <b style="color:white;">Precio Total</b>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @Model.FilasDetalle
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

¿Que puedo estar haciendo mal?

Saludos!

Comment: No controlo mucho de razor, pero entiendo que tienes que usar un `foreach` en tu plantilla, algo como `@foreach (var item in Model.FilasDetalle)
{`...Tal como lo tienes, está haciendo un `ToString` de `FilasDetalle`, por eso te aparece lo que ves

Comment: @Pikoh la plantilla es un simple `html` entonces para aplicar razor necestitaria un `cshtml`. se ve como `string` porque la plantilla la tomo como un `string`

Comment: Cuando lo depuras ves `System.Collections.Generic.List``1[CrearReportePDF.Models.DetalleFactura]`. Eso es porque tienes en la plantilla `@Model.FilasDetalle`, y se está haciendo un `ToString` de ello. Como digo no tengo experiencia en Razor, pero apostaría que el problema está ahí y que necesitas un `foreach`...

Comment: Es exactamente como dice @Pikoh, ya sea un `foreach` o un `for` pero tenes que iterar `FilasDetalle`

Comment: Me parece que esta mal en el html los `th` son para encabezado y lod `td` son para escribir los datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si `FilasDetalle` es una lista deberias iterar para crear las rows

```
<table border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#F5B041" style="font-size:8.0pt;">
            <td width="8" valign="top" align="left">
                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Principal</b>
            </td>
            <td width="7" valign="top" align="left">
                <b style="color:white;">Cód. Auxiliar</b>
            </td>
            <td width="6" valign="top" align="left">
                <b style="color:white;">Cant.</b>
            </td>
            <td width="40" valign="top" align="left">
                <b style="color:white;">Descripción</b>
            </td>
            <td width="20" valign="top" align="left">
                <b style="color:white;">Detalle Adicional</b>
            </td>
            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                <b style="color:white;">P/U</b>
            </td>
            <td width="5" valign="top" align="right">
                <b style="color:white;">Desc.</b>
            </td>
            <td width="7" valign="top" align="right">
                <b style="color:white;">Precio Total</b>
            </td>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var detalle in Model.FilasDetalle) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @detalle.CodigoPrincipal
                </td>
                <td>
                    @detalle.Cantidad
                </td>
                <td>
                    @detalle.PrecioUnitario 
                </td>
                <td>
                    @detalle.Descuento  
                </td>
                <td>
                    @detalle.PrecioTotal  
                </td>
            <tr>
        }

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Esto esta en la documentacion

[1. About Razor and its syntax](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine/wiki/1.-About-Razor-and-its-syntax)

Comment: No pensé que en un simple html se podría aplicar razor, solo pensaba que se podía hacer solo en los archivos cshtml.

Comment: estas usando un motor de render, usar una extension es solo para diferenciar el tipo de archivo y que el IDE pueda aplicar intellisense